# Predicting with model gives different predictions for same inputs and loading the model throws "doesnt save pytorch_model.bin cannot be opened" error

Tags: python, machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, machine-learning-model

I am predicting my model like this:

```
def predict_label(text,username):
    # input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode(text)).unsqueeze(0)
    model=getmodelfromusername(username)
    input_ids=tokenizer(text, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=500, return_tensors="pt")
    logits = model(**input_ids)[0]
    probs = torch.nn.functional.softmax(logits, dim=1)
    
    return probs
```

I am training like this:

```
def train_and_update_model(model, parseddata, code, username,number):

    optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=4e-5)

    lr_scheduler = get_scheduler(
        name="linear", optimizer=optimizer, num_warmup_steps=0, num_training_steps=2
    )

    input_ids = torch.tensor([tokenizer.encode(str(parseddata), add_special_tokens=True)])
    labels = torch.tensor([number])

    # del banmodel

    model.train(mode=True)

    for i in range(2):
        outputs = model(input_ids, labels=labels)
        loss = outputs[0]
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        lr_scheduler.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

    with lock:
        model.save_pretrained(username + "/CustomModel")

    with lock:
        model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(username + '/CustomModel')
    changemodelwithcode(code, model)
```

In my application sometimes I'm gonna need to predict a lot of text that is incoming and also at the same time I need to be able to train at any moment. However, I also get this error when I try to do that:

```
at: model.save_pretrained(username + "/CustomModel")
RuntimeError: File test/CustomModel\pytorch_model.bin cannot be opened.
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated thanks

Comment: Which model is this? What dataset are you predicting on? What's your transformers version?

Comment: bert uncased, custom text dataset, pretty sure the latest

Comment: Take a look at the code snippet in the answer. Your training code should still work if you load the model and tokenizer using AutoModel.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `AutoModel` classes and it would help a lot in the model saving/loading, e.g.

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

model.save_pretrained('mybert')


mybert_model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('./mybert')
mybert_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
```

Then for inference you can use `pipeline`,
https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/pipelines e.g.

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer
from transformers import pipeline

mybert_model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('./mybert')
mybert_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

classifier = pipeline("text-classification", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
print(classifier(['this is a sentence', 'foo bar']))
print(classifier(['this is a sentence', 'foo bar']))
print(classifier(['this is a sentence', 'foo bar']))
```

[out]:

```
[{'label': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.5042521357536316},
 {'label': 'LABEL_0', 'score': 0.5395587682723999}]

[{'label': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.5042521357536316},
 {'label': 'LABEL_0', 'score': 0.5395587682723999}]

[{'label': 'LABEL_1', 'score': 0.5042521357536316},
 {'label': 'LABEL_0', 'score': 0.5395587682723999}]
```

Comment: So i've change the model to an automodel however, after training the model, I am still getting different scores for the same input

Comment: Did you use pipeline to load the model? Or set the model to eval mode?

Comment: yes I used pipeline, how can i set it to eval mode?

Comment: Are you sure it's BERT uncased model? And the data is the same? Could you post your code and the sample of the data you're testing on?

Comment: yup im sure it bert. With any text data i put in it, after training it gives different predictions everytime and the scores are not constant.

Comment: Wait a minute, are you training or using the model?

Comment: If you're running inference (i.e. using the model), you don't need to train. Just use the pipeline. But if you're training the model in different runs, it's very possible that there's some randomness and determinism is not guaranteed unless you go to all the places thats randomness can exist in the model to standardize i.t